# Django registration: Redirect after login

Tags: django, django-urls, django-generic-views

I am using django registration and I want to be redirected on an other page after login.
I used in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/'
```

That's the page I want to be redirected to.

I succeed in redirecting. But the page home must display some elements from my database, and there is nothing. The elements exists in the db (I checked).

Any idea please ?
TY

My first url conf (url conf of django) => urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('dashboard.registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^home/$', direct_to_template,{ 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
url(r'^home/', include(dashboard.home.urls)),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My second url conf (dashboard.home.urls)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('dashboard.home.views',
    url(r'^$',index,name='index'),
)
```

My index request in dashboard.home.views

```
def index(request):
    print 'index request'
    project_list = Project.objects.all().order_by('project_name')
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'project_list': project_list})
```

My template index.html

```
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>

    <h3>Home</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Add_Project/">Add a Project</a></li>

    </ul>

    <h3>Project list</h3>
    {% if project_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for project in project_list %}
            <li> <a href={{project.project_name}}>{{ project.project_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no Projects</p>
    {% endif %} 

{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

My settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/'
```

Comment: does it show content, when you call it directly?? You could show us some code like your view, model(s) and html template...

Comment: No it doesn't. When I'm not logged, it shows 'Welcome, new user. Please log in.' When I'm logged, it shows everything and 'There are no Projects' whereas there are projects.

Comment: So your project list seems to be empty. Check your model and your query. Try to execute your query in the shell to see whether it has results.

Comment: It has a results. Using advice from Burhan Khalid, I tried, I have the project list because I print it on console. But I have not the project list on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url(r'^home/$', direct_to_template,{ 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
url(r'^home/', include(dashboard.home.urls)),
```

Django will stop at the first match, so your other include urls won't be called if the url is `/home/`. Only the first pattern will match, and `index.html` will be shown.

You should also pass `RequestContext`, easiest way is to use the [`render`](http://dango.me/render) shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    project_list = Project.objects.all().order_by('project_name')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'project_list': project_list})
```

In addition make sure you have not removed `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"` from `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (its there by default, unless you removed it).

EDIT:

> I tried, I have the project list because I print it on console. But I
>   have not the project list on my page.

Your project list will only print if you have a valid user; if you are logged in as guest, then your project list won't print anything.

Try this as your template:

```
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}

    <h3>Home</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Add_Project/">Add a Project</a></li>

    </ul>

    <h3>Project list</h3>
    {% if project_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for project in project_list %}
            <li> <a href={{project.project_name}}>{{ project.project_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no Projects</p>
    {% endif %} 

</body>
```

And adjust your `index` method:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    project_list = Project.objects.all().order_by('project_name')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'project_list': project_list})
```

Comment: I removed :    url(r'^home/$', direct_to_template,{ 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'). But the user is not recognized when redirected.

Comment: I checked and did the change. But I have the same problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Your question is about redirection - is it redirecting correctly?

Comment: Actually, my question was about redirection, because I thought it was the only problem. But Thanks, your render method fixed the problem.